# Can Windows phone 8 SDK be installed on a Windows 8 32 bit machine

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have been trying to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK on a Windows 8 (x86) machine. But to no avail even though I read somewhere on the site that it will install but I will not be able to run the emulator.

Is Microsoft serious that Win Phone 8 apps can only be developed on 64-bit machines?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

They make it quite clear the x64 is required on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471):

> Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions

I can't say with any authority, but I suspect it is because the emulator uses Hyper-V, which [also requires x64](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx):

> Hyper-V requires a 64-bit system that has Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).

Comment: The latter is indeed why it's a requirement.

Comment: I have a 64-bit processor without SLAT support and was able to install the Windows 8 Phone SDK. However, I did get an installation warning indicating that I could not use emulation. So it is possible to use the SDK and not have SLAT support.

Comment: You also need Windows 8 Professional, and not RTM. (And don't get me started on Windows RT and lack of support or tools for that shitty tablet I bought in December).

Comment: I have Windows 7 Ultimate, 64 bit and I got this error message. Cannot install it.

Comment: Any workarounds? (Other than buy a new laptop)