# Windows phone on 32 bit os

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want develop windows phone apps here is my system information:

os: windows 8 pro (32 bit), processor : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+ , Ram: 2.5 gb and the real question is "Can i develop windows phone 8 apps?"

P.S.:I already tried run windows phone sdk setup but it dumped error

Comment: Yes, but you can't run the emulator.

Comment: but how then install it??

Comment: you need a 64bit version to install SDK

Comment: Install 64-bit Windows, your processor is capable of running it, though it might be a bit slow without more RAM

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Windows phone 8 SDK be installed on a Windows 8 32 bit machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158729/can-windows-phone-8-sdk-be-installed-on-a-windows-8-32-bit-machine)

Comment: @SLaks okey i citate myself : (the real question is "Can i develop windows phone 8 apps?"), so its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i can develop Windows phone apps.

To develop apps you must have installed Windows 8 64 bit os (on 32 bit os you can't install SDK and compile apps).

Answer (score 1):

To install `mongoDB` on `windows 32bi x86 OS`

download from here  - https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-2.6.1.zip

1) download the zip of mongodb for windows 
2) extract in **any drive** example **D:**
3) create 2 directories named **log**, **data**
**log** - is where the logs of the server would be created 
**data**  - is where mongo will accumulate the data

4) create a **mongo.config** file and then configure the file by writing some of the changes

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

port= 27017

quite = true  // so that critical errors are logged \

dbpath = D:\mongodb\db

logpath = D:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

logappend = true // Is set this to true so that the log is not overwritten upon restart of mongod.


diaglog=3 // log read and write operations
```

It ensures write durability and data consistency much as any journaling scheme would be expected to do. 
Only set this to false if you don’t really care about your data (or more so, the loss of it).

`journal = true`